# Rendimiento Variables Tipo Tabla Vs Tablas Temporales

Tags: sql-server, sql, rendimiento

Estoy en un proceso de calculo de datos; pero necesito saber que es más optimo con respecto a las **Variables tipo Tabla** vs **Tablas Temporales**, para operaciones de Join, MAX, SUM, entre otras; para un aproximado de 9 millones de registros por empresa, donde puede ser más de 10 empresas. En este momento tengo implementado variables tipo tablas con indices como el siguiente.

Nota:Se está realizando el proceso de los calculos por empresa.

```
DECLARE @tbVhiObjFacturas AS TABLE(
        emp_codigo INT INDEX IX_VHI_OBJ_FACTURAS NONCLUSTERED (can_codigo, ven_codigo),
        can_codigo VARCHAR(8),
        ven_codigo VARCHAR(16),
        vhi_numero_factura VARCHAR(50),
        ove_valor FLOAT
    )
```

De igual forma saber en que casos debo utilizar las variables tipo Tabla, y en que casos tablas temporales.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Debo aclarar que lo que estoy a punto de recalcar, se va a solucionar o ha sido solucionado en la más reciente versión de SQL Server.

Las variables tipo tabla tienen un gran problema en cuanto a rendimiento contra las tablas temporales. El problema es que las variables tipo tabla no tienen estadísticas y siempre se calcula que tienen una fila (no registro) al generar los planes de ejecución. Esto quiere decir, que en vez de utilizar operaciones físicas óptimas para grandes volúmenes de datos (como 90 millones) se van a utilizar operaciones físicas para pocas filas. Por ejemplo, se usará un Nested Loops Join en vez de un Hash Join.

Este es un factor importante además de los ya expuestos por otros, como la incapacidad de tener múltiples índices.

Otro dato a resaltar, es que no hay mucha diferencia en como se maneja el almacenamiento de ambos tipos de tablas. Los dos tipos empezarán en memoria (con su definición en tempdb) y después de alcanzar cierto límite (que varía según la configuración de la instancia) se almacenan físicamente en tempdb. Por lo tanto, ninguna de las dos opciones tiene ventajas por estar solo en memoria.

Answer (score 1):

¿Rendimiento en dos enfoques? No creo que las tablas temporales sean siempre más rápidas ... el enfoque con la variable de tabla me parece mucho más limpio e intuitivo.

Pero puede definirlo en el procedimiento almacenado de llamada. Tenga en cuenta que esto solo funcionará para procedimientos almacenados. No puede acceder a tablas temporales desde dentro de las funciones.

Asegúrese de usar ##tableName para asegurarse de que la tabla sea accesible globalmente (fuera del SPID actual)

La ventaja de una tabla temporal es si necesita hacer varias operaciones con esos datos...pero hasta ahí llega.

ver el link siguiente [Enla extenso](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386)

1.Si tiene una opción, algunas sugerencias están a continuación (aunque el método más confiable es simplemente probar ambas con su carga de trabajo específica).

2.Si necesita un índice que no se puede crear en una variable de tabla, entonces, por supuesto, necesitará una #temporarytabla. Sin embargo, los detalles de esto dependen de la versión. Para SQL Server 2012 y posteriores, los únicos índices que se podían crear en las variables de la tabla eran aquellos creados implícitamente mediante una restricción UNIQUEo PRIMARY KEY. SQL Server 2014 introdujo la sintaxis de índice en línea para un subconjunto de las opciones disponibles en CREATE INDEX. Esto se ha extendido desde entonces para permitir condiciones de índice filtradas. INCLUDESin embargo, todavía no es posible crear índices con columnas -d o índices de almacén de columnas en las variables de tabla.

3.Si va a agregar y eliminar repetidamente un gran número de filas de la tabla, use una #temporarytabla. Eso admite TRUNCATE(que es más eficiente que DELETEpara tablas grandes) y, además, las inserciones posteriores que siguen a TRUNCATEpueden tener un mejor rendimiento que las que siguen a DELETE como se ilustra aquí .

4.Si va a eliminar o actualizar una gran cantidad de filas, entonces la tabla temporal puede funcionar mucho mejor que una variable de tabla, si es capaz de usar el intercambio de conjuntos de filas (consulte "Efectos de compartir conjuntos de filas" a continuación para ver un ejemplo).
Si el plan óptimo que usa la tabla variará dependiendo de los datos, use una #temporarytabla. Eso admite la creación de estadísticas que permite que el plan se vuelva a compilar dinámicamente de acuerdo con los datos (aunque para las tablas temporales en caché en los procedimientos almacenados, el comportamiento de la compilación debe entenderse por separado).
5.Si es poco probable que el plan óptimo para la consulta que usa la tabla cambie, entonces puede considerar una variable de tabla para omitir la sobrecarga de la creación de estadísticas y recompilaciones (posiblemente requeriría sugerencias para arreglar el plan que desea).
6.Si la fuente de los datos insertados en la tabla proviene de una SELECTdeclaración potencialmente costosa , entonces considere que usar una variable de tabla bloqueará la posibilidad de que esto use un plan paralelo.
7.Si necesita los datos de la tabla para sobrevivir a una reversión de una transacción de usuario externo, utilice una variable de tabla. Un posible caso de uso para esto podría ser registrar el progreso de diferentes pasos en un lote SQL largo.

8.Cuando se usa una #temptabla dentro de una transacción de usuario, los bloqueos se pueden mantener más tiempo que para las variables de la tabla (potencialmente hasta el final de la transacción frente al final de la declaración dependiendo del tipo de bloqueo y nivel de aislamiento) y también puede evitar el truncamiento del tempdbregistro de transacciones hasta que la transacción del usuario finaliza. Entonces esto podría favorecer el uso de variables de tabla.

9.Dentro de las rutinas almacenadas, se pueden almacenar en caché tanto las variables de tabla como las tablas temporales. El mantenimiento de metadatos para las variables de la tabla en caché es menor que el de las #temporarytablas. Bob Ward señala en su tempdbpresentación que esto puede causar contención adicional en las tablas del sistema en condiciones de alta concurrencia. Además, cuando se trata con pequeñas cantidades de datos, esto puede marcar diferencia : [rendimientos](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/why-is-using-a-table-variable-more-than-twice-as-fast-as-a-temp-table-in-this-s/13412#13412)

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente el rendimiento no debiera ser el motivo principal para decidir por uno u otro enfoque. Ambos objetos se mantienen físicamente en la `tempdb`, por lo que en líneas generales podríamos esperar una performance similar.

Aún así, las tablas temporales son más flexibles a la hora de definir índices, lo cual, eventualmente, puede redundar en una mejora de performance en las consultas, en particular en un escenario de millones de filas como el que mencionas y alguna consulta que pueda aprovechar un índice que no puedas crear en una variable tipo tabla y si con una temporal.

Ahora bien, ¿cuándo una u otra? El siguiente es un resumen de algunas de las características, para mi gusto, más significativas:

#### Tabla temporal si:

- Necesitamos "rollbaquear" el contenido de estas en una transacción
- Necesitamos "compartir" los datos entre múltiples Sp´s anidados, incluso un `sp_execute_sql`
- Necesitamos implementar más de un índice o un índice no único para optimizar una consulta
- Necesitamos constraints, o queremos usar un `SELECT .. INTO` o un `ALTER`
- Queremos usar un `TRUNCATE`que es siempre más performante que un `DELETE`
- Si la recompilación de un Sp tiene un efecto positivo

#### Variable tipo Tabla si:

- Necesitamos crearla o usarla dentro de una función
- Necesitamos usar el `collation` del database y no el de la `tempdb`
- Queremos usar parámetros tipo tabla para pasar información, por ej: `CREATE TYPE MiTabla AS TABLE (...)` y luego `CREATE PROCEDURE MiSp(@TableName MiTabla READONLY)`
- Necesitamos "persistir" datos aún en caso de un `ROLLBACK`
- Si la recompilación no ofrece ninguna ventaja, las variables tipo tabla, al no forzar esta pueden evitar este "overhead"

#### Documentación relacionada

- [What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)
- [SQL Server Temp Table vs Table Variable Performance Testing](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2825/sql-server-temp-table-vs-table-variable-performance-testing/)